# Windows 7 - CreateProcess w/ DEBUG_PROCESS Access Violation

Tags: c++, windows, visual-studio, windows-7, windows-xp

ok...burned out on this one...scratching my head all day. I have a very simple, single purpose c++ DLL (StartApplication.dll) used to start an application.

- Works fine in WinXP, but not in win7
- Uses CreateProcess() with DEBUG_PROCESS (so i can wait for the program to finish before terminating).
- If I monitor processes in Task Manager, I can see the process start, but no window is created and nothing further happens
- If I change to NORMAL_PRIORITY_CLASS, the program will execute as it should (but i lose the ability to wait around before terminating as I can only do this while debugging)
- Error code gives me STATUS_ACCESS_VIOLATION
- I have UAC turned off and setting the executable to run as Administrator and with WinXP compatibility does nothing

Heres the code. Any thoughts would be greatly appreciated

```
    //...blah blah...handful of stuff preceding this to set up command line and
    //directories etc....not of use here probably...

SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES sa = {0}; sa.nLength = sizeof(SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES);
sa.bInheritHandle = TRUE;

STARTUPINFO si = {0}; si.cb = sizeof(si);
si.dwFlags = STARTF_USESTDHANDLES;

si.hStdOutput = (NULL == stdOutFileName)? INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE :
    ::CreateFile(stdOutFileName, GENERIC_WRITE, FILE_SHARE_READ, &sa
        , CREATE_ALWAYS, 0, NULL);

si.hStdError = (NULL == stdErrFileName)? INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE :
    ::CreateFile(stdErrFileName, GENERIC_WRITE, FILE_SHARE_READ, &sa
        , CREATE_ALWAYS, 0, NULL)        
PROCESS_INFORMATION pi = {0};
if (::CreateProcess(useApplicationName? applicationName : NULL, processCommandLine
    , NULL, NULL, TRUE, /*NORMAL_PRIORITY_CLASS*/DEBUG_PROCESS, NULL, currentDirectory, &si, &pi)) 
{
    BOOL cont = TRUE;
    while (cont) 
    {
        DWORD continueStatus = DBG_CONTINUE;

        DEBUG_EVENT debugEvent = {0};
        if (!::WaitForDebugEvent(&debugEvent, INFINITE)) 
        { 
            errorCode = ErrorCode_Other;
            ::TerminateProcess(pi.hProcess, 0);
            break;
        }
        else
        {
            switch (debugEvent.dwDebugEventCode) 
            {
                case EXCEPTION_DEBUG_EVENT: 
                    switch (debugEvent.u.Exception.ExceptionRecord.ExceptionCode) 
                    {
                        case EXCEPTION_ACCESS_VIOLATION:
                        case EXCEPTION_DATATYPE_MISALIGNMENT:
                        case EXCEPTION_ARRAY_BOUNDS_EXCEEDED:
                        case EXCEPTION_FLT_DENORMAL_OPERAND: 
                        case EXCEPTION_FLT_DIVIDE_BY_ZERO:
                        case EXCEPTION_FLT_INEXACT_RESULT:
                        case EXCEPTION_FLT_INVALID_OPERATION:
                        case EXCEPTION_FLT_OVERFLOW:
                        case EXCEPTION_FLT_STACK_CHECK:
                        case EXCEPTION_FLT_UNDERFLOW:
                        case EXCEPTION_INT_DIVIDE_BY_ZERO:
                        case EXCEPTION_INT_OVERFLOW:
                        case EXCEPTION_PRIV_INSTRUCTION:
                        case EXCEPTION_IN_PAGE_ERROR:
                        case EXCEPTION_ILLEGAL_INSTRUCTION:
                        case EXCEPTION_NONCONTINUABLE_EXCEPTION:
                        case EXCEPTION_STACK_OVERFLOW:
                        case EXCEPTION_INVALID_DISPOSITION:
                        case EXCEPTION_INVALID_HANDLE:
                            errorCode = ErrorCode_ApplicationException; 
                            *exceptionCode = debugEvent.u.Exception.
                                ExceptionRecord.ExceptionCode;
                            ::TerminateProcess(pi.hProcess, 0);
                            break;
                        default:
                            ;
                    }
                    break;

                case EXIT_PROCESS_DEBUG_EVENT:
                    cont = FALSE;   
                    break;
                default:
                    ;
            } 
            ::ContinueDebugEvent(debugEvent.dwProcessId, debugEvent.dwThreadId
                , continueStatus);
        }    
    }

    ::GetExitCodeProcess(pi.hProcess, reinterpret_cast<LPDWORD>(exitCode));

    ::CloseHandle(pi.hProcess);
    ::CloseHandle(pi.hThread);
}
if (INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE != si.hStdOutput)
    ::CloseHandle(si.hStdOutput);
if (INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE != si.hStdError)
    ::CloseHandle(si.hStdError);

return errorCode;
```

}

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code terminates the whole process after the first exception occures.
Normally you should let the program take care of exceptions, only if the exception wasn't handled the process will terminate.

To see if an exception was fatal (ie. not handled the first time around) check `u.Exception.dwFirstChance`:

- If it's 0, set your error codes accordingly and terminate.
- otherwise, the exception occured for the first time, you should call `ContinueDebugEvent` with `DBG_EXCEPTION_NOT_HANDLED` to pass the exception to the process.

**EDIT**

If you only want to watch exceptions and not handle them from inside the debugger, you should always continue with `DBG_EXCEPTION_NOT_HANDLED`.

There's one catch:

Right before the main thread starts, Windows raises an INT3 exception which *needs to be passed* to the process (`DBG_CONTINUE`).

Pseudo code:

```
bool FirstInt3 = true;

while (cont) 
{
    DWORD continueStatus = DBG_EXCEPTION_NOT_HANDLED;

    // ....

    switch(...)
    {
        case EXCEPTION_DEBUG_EVENT: 
            if(!FirstChance)
            {
                // Fatal exception

                // Log Exception that terminated the program here
                // Don't do anything else, Windows automatically terminates the process
                // You will get an EXIT_PROCESS_DEBUG_EVENT on the next event
            }
            switch (debugEvent.u.Exception.ExceptionRecord.ExceptionCode) 
            {
                case EXCEPTION_BREAKPOINT:
                    if(FirstInt3)
                    {
                        FirstInt3 = false;
                        continueStatus = DBG_CONTINUE;
                        break;
                    }
                default:
                    // Log ExceptionCode here
                    break;
            }
            break;
    }
```

Comment: @Ajay as well: I added the ".dwFirstChance != 0" condition, setting the continueStatus prior to the terminate in the EXCEPTION_DEBUG_EVENT switch. It simply does another loop and terminates on the next.  I'm a bit of a novice to coding myself (i didn't write this originally), so if i put that in a bad spot then let me know. (or if there are parts of the process i can nuke altogether).  If i rearrange things i can get the cmd window to popup as desired, but it hangs and does nothing until terminated. Might i need to be setting some windows 7 permission of some sort in order to execute properly?

Comment: @0xDEADFACE updated my answer, hope that clarifies things a little.

Comment: ah there we go. handling the INT3 exception was the missing link there. had to tweak things a little to handle termination gracefully, but that worked like a charm. thanks a bunch guys.

Comment: @0xDEADFACE Glad I could help. PS: you can accept the right answer by clicking on the check mark next to it

Comment: @0xDEADFACE would you mind sending me your c++ code in a PM or email? I struggle with the same problem (Stefan Olson's Splash Screen?) but I'm not that good in C++ to find the solution based on what pezcode writes here.

Answer (score 2):

If I've understand you correctly, you're using DEBUG_PROCESS just so that you can wait until the process exits.  That's major overkill.

To wait until the process has exited, use WaitForSingleObject (or another wait function as appropriate) on pi.hProcess.

Comment: well i do need to send any exception codes back so the debug process is necessary. poor wording in my intro i suppose

Answer (score 1):

@pezcode is right - don't just end the process on receiving first exception from the debuggee, let it run normally. Debugger (your code) will anyway receive all exceptions occurring in the debuggee (first chance exceptions).

I would suggest you to first minimize the debugger-loop logic, and also try not to attach and handles to process. Keep it simple first, then move ahead.